# Where can I find VBSQL.VBX?

Tags: vbx

I've been given the task of re-engineering a really old VB3 application.  As part of this I have an XP virtual workstation upon which I've installed VB3 Pro, so I can create a running verison of it to help me emulate it, but the VB3 app uses a control called VBSQL.VBX, which didn't come with VB3 Pro, apparently.  I've checked Microsoft's site, but there are only seven pages in the search result for VBSQL.VBX, and none of them offers an install.

Does anyone here have any idea where on earth I can obtain VBSQL.VBX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111490, "Microsoft SQL Server Programmer's Toolkit for Visual Basic".

It looks like they offer the .ocx here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186893, possibly there is a VBX as well?

Comment: Yes!  The VBX was there, as you said.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into an issue like this I usually end up creating a mock object with the same public members as the class in question. Sometimes it works out better as I can fake the data I want to pass around so I can run tests that would otherwise prove difficult.

If you can't find this file this is the approach I would recommend.